# Jquery toggling outside of div using 'this'

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to toggle a mobile menu, when I click .dropdown-toggle I'm wanting the drop down menu to show. However in my jquery because .dropdown-toggle is outside the div when I'm using "this" it's not working. I need to use this because I will be using more dropdowns. Any ideas to get it working?

The code works if I take "this' out but then it opens all of the dropdowns.

```
        <ul id="mob_nav">
                <li id="dropdown" <?php if (is_tree(33)) echo 'class="selected"'; ?>>
                    <a class="orange">Making a claim</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-toggle">&#62;</div>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="" href="">Medical negligence</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-toggle-sub">&#62;</div>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu-sub">
                                    <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>

                <li <?php if (is_tree(35)) echo 'class="selected"'; ?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/types-of-claims" class="red">Types of claims</a></li>
                <li <?php if (is_tree(37)) echo 'class="selected"'; ?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/compensation-calculator" class="blue">Compensation calculator</a></li>
                <li <?php if (is_page(320)) echo 'class="selected"'; ?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/about/charity" class="purple">Charity</a></li>
                <li <?php if (is_page(10)) echo 'class="selected"'; ?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/about" class="green">About</a></li>
        </ul>
<script>
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).toggle();
    });

    $('.dropdown-toggle-sub').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu-sub', this).toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried, or any research you've done for possibly solving this

Comment: Hi George, the above code is my attempt at it, I also tried to wrap dropdown-toggle but then the whole thing became a button. The code works if I take "this' out but then it opens all of the dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function(){
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});

$('.dropdown-toggle-sub').on("click", function(){
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu-sub').toggle();
});
```

We're getting the next element with the desired class and then toggle it.

Comment: Thank you, you have saved me many hours! I didn't know about .next!

Comment: @JonnyJordan there's always a path ! Glad I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown menu is not a child of the toggle. It's the next sibling.

```
$(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
```

Same thing with the other one.

```
$(this).next('.dropdown-menu-sub').toggle();
```